# Why sublime 3 yellow-hightlight all ID selectors in css?

Tags: css, sublimetext, sublimetext3

A picture says a thousand word:

Sublime 3 (build3083).  It is highlighting all `#something` selector as yellow warning. `.classtag` is otherwise all okay.

I don't work on CSS all that often but it is annoying.
**How do I get rid of the yellow warning on correct ?**

[image: enter image description heres]

Also, I don't have a lot of packages installed. Don't know if any of them is a problem.

```js
{
    "in_process_packages":
    [
    ],
    "installed_packages":
    [
        "Alignment",
        "HighlightWords",
        "Laravel Blade Highlighter",
        "Package Control",
        "PhalconPHP Completions",
        "PhpDoc",
        "SFTP",
        "SideBarEnhancements",
        "SourceTree",
        "SublimeCodeIntel",
        "SublimeLinter",
        "SublimeLinter-csslint",
        "SublimeLinter-jshint",
        "SublimeLinter-php",
        "Theme - Cobalt2",
        "Volt"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please open `Packages/User/Package Control.sublime-settings` and add the contents of the `"installed_packages"` array to your question. Many ST3 plugins are stored as `.sublime-package` zip files and don't show up as folders within `Packages`.

Comment: @MattDMo thanks for the help. I didn't even know where to look for this list.

Comment: So the highlighting is most likely being initiated by `SublimeLinter-csslint`. I suggest you alter the settings so that the actual errors/warnings are shown somewhere so you can fix them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MattDMo has pointed out, csslint just treat all ID selectors as warning.

https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/wiki/Disallow-IDs-in-selectors

> Rule ID: ids
>
> This rule is aimed at improving maintainability by flagging the use of
>   IDs in selectors. Every instance of an ID will result in a warning.

Well, I feel that I have a valid reason to use ID selector in CSS. Just uninstall csslint.